# Collapse Navigation on left menu on Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

We're migrating from SP 2007 to SP 2013.
We'd some JS code that would collapse the links on the left side of the page but it doesn't work in SP 2013.
The code would leave a link for the main sites but collapse all links to subsites (unless you were on a main site)

eg if ( click on 1)
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
2
3

and if I click on 3
1
2
3
3.1
3.2
3.3

But the SP 2013 doesn't seem to contain the id's on the anchor tags

2013 renders like this

2007 renders like this
Media Coverage Admin

Is there any way to do this in SP 2013?

Thanks
p

Comment: 2013 renders like this

    <a class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="/CompanyInformation/Communications/Pages/MediaCoverageAdmin.aspx">

2007 renders like this

    <a class="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_CurrentNav_0 anPost-nodeLevel2 ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_CurrentNav_3" href="/CompanyInformation/Communications/Pages/MediaCoverageAdmin.aspx" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_CurrentNavn2" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Media Coverage Admin</a>

Comment: I just found a script that does this but I'd like it to 1) automatically show the current subsites (it currently hides subsites) 2) not show the number of subsites in brackets thanks https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aad7b81c-2898-43db-bf36-9a6fbcaf97ba/forum-faqcollapse-or-expand-the-quick-launch-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: sorry and also remove the plus minus sign and make the link clickable